# Did the actors sing for Pitch Perfect?

Tags: soundtrack, pitch-perfect

I was quite baffled after watching *Pitch Perfect* because the songs were really enticing. Moreover, I felt that the songs in the movie were much better than the original songs.

**Did the actors really sing in the movie?**

Comment: If you know spin and you read those answers carefully, you can see that what you hear in the movie may be pro singers dubbed over. I'm not saying I know for a fact, just that the language in those quotes is not exactly definitive.

Comment: Obviously related, though not *quite* the same question: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/9433/did-the-soundtrack-of-pitch-perfect-cheat-and-use-instruments?rq=1

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I believe that the cast did in fact sing all of the songs in the movie. Some are even professional a capella singers.

From [People's Choice](http://blog.peopleschoice.com/2014/11/26/pitch-perfect-surprising-movie-facts/)

> 1. Everyone in the films who plays a singing part had to sing a full song
>      for their audition.
> 2. Any time protagonist Beca, played by Anna Kendrick, was singing alone, she was singing live on set.
> 3. Kelley Jackle, Adam DeVine’s (aka Bumper) girlfriend, plays Barden Bella Jessica in the film (rivalry!) and is actually a professional a capella singer in real life.

From [Huffington Post](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2012/10/09/pitch-perfect-soundtrack_n_1952044.html)

> Adam DeVine [who plays TheTreblemakers' lead singer] is a great
>   singer. Lots of confidence. In fact, he's probably as good as a lot of
>   other singers we work with. He was really prepared, he knew all his
>   lines, he knew the song really well and he knew what he could do with
>   his voice.

From [The Ganon Knight](http://www.gannonknight.com/?p=5058)

> Kendrick’s voice range is definitely lower than a lot of the other girls, so it helps to harmonize as several of the girls in the a cappella group have noticeably higher voices.
>
> Wilson also had a really good voice and did a profoundly good job when it came to exemplifying her character while singing.
>
> Snow shines in her solos at the beginning of the movie where people get to hear her high-range voice

Comment: Did the soft-spoken Lilly Onakuramara sing too?

Comment: @Pacerier not too sure about the singing part, but she did beat box though. http://www.younghollywood.com/scene/a-pitch-perfect-chat-with-rising-star-hana-mae-lee.html

Comment: It's worth noting that some of the cast (Anna Kendrick for example) grew up doing musical theatre so she's been singing for years. It's just that we're only used to seeing her act on screen - her Autobiography isn't bad for a bit of background on what she did before she was famous

Answer (score -5):

No they never sing in the movie they do lip sing.  First they record the singers voice and after actors and actor do lip sing